# ¿Se puede hostear una pagina web en .NET a Firebase?

Tags: asp.net, firebase, hosting

Mi pregunta es sí ¿alguien probó hostear una aplicación en `asp.net` en el hosting gratuito de `firebase`?

Aclaro que en mi caso es una pagina estática, sin base de datos (solo paginas `aspx`, `HTML,` `JavaScript`, `CSS`)

Comment: Pues lo dudo bastante la verdad. Firebase creo que solo sirve contenido estático (HTML, JS, CSS...),asi que no creo que pueda interpretar aspx. De todas maneras, si segun dices la página es estática, para que necesitas aspx? Hazlo con html...

Comment: Entonces la página no es .NET pues si es estático y no ocupas bd entonces usa lo que te comentan arriba

Comment: @shadow  La app web la compile con Visual Studio, tiene paginas .aspx y algunos elementos de ASP como botones. Nada mas. La hice en .NET porque en el futuro quiero implementar sql en ese proyecto, pero por ahora es una web estatica con algunos elementos ASP

Comment: Considero que hasta que no implementes una bd no hay necesidad de eso, tener elementos del frontend generados no debe afectar en un futuro

Comment: Hola Oren. Sólo puedes alojar contenido estático en el CDN de FireBase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart?hl=es-419.